# How do I compile generated files after npm Build

Tags: c#, asp.net, npm, msbuild, .net-7.0

I have C# code that is generated when I run `npm run build`. This code needs to be compiled along with the build (I think this is correct) to be found.

When I add an item group and a compile to my csproj like below, it works to recognize everything fine.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="codegenerator\generated\**\*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However, the build fails because the `generated` folder only exists after the `npm run build` command finishes. So, I tried to split this up into targets that depend on each other like below:

```xml
  <Target Name="NpmInstall" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="npm install" WorkingDirectory="codegenerator" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="NpmRunBuild" DependsOnTargets="NpmInstall" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="npm run build" WorkingDirectory="codegenerator" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="CompileGeneratedCode" DependsOnTargets="NpmRunBuild" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="codegenerator\generated\**\*.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

With this, the code builds and runs fine, but I get errors in the class files that none of the generated code can be found. This makes it hard to develop since I can't go to any sources.

I am developing in VSCode with the C# and C#-dev-kit extensions.

Is there a way to generate the files during the build and have my code see the generated code?

Comment: Is the `npm run build` command generating the files under the 'generated' folder or under the 'codegenerator' folder?

Comment: "When I add an item group and a compile to my csproj like below ...". You are not adding 'a compile'. There is an item group (collection) named `Compile` and you are adding additional items to the collection. The `@(Compile)` item collection is later passed to the C# compiler.

Comment: There was a mistake in my folder structure. I updated the question with the correct one. The generated files live in `codegenerator\generated\*` folder.

Comment: The order of your targets is good. That is not the issue. The tasks will run in the following order: `NpmInstall`, `NpmRunBuild`, `CompileGeneratedCode`, `BeforeBuild` (You can add a `Message` task to each target to confirm.)

Comment: You can add `<Message Text="@(Compile, '$([System.Environment]::NewLine)')" />` (or `<Message Text="@(Compile, '%0d%0a')" />` for MSBuild versions prior to v17.3)  inside the `CompileGeneratedCode` target after the `ItemGroup`. That will display the members of `Compile` delimited by an EOL, i.e. one item per line.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/5570 I found an open issue about this. Doesn't look like there is a good answer for this yet. I have just included the generated code in git for now so all future builds will succeed and Intellisense can see the code by just adding the `ItemGroup/Compile` without the `Target`.

Comment: Your question title was "How do I compile generated files after npm Build". You should be able to generate the files and then compile the generated files into the assembly. Unless -- is the build working and your actual issue is that the editor IntelliSense is complaining?

Comment: Both issues exist separately. When I use the `ItemGroup/Compile` alone, IntelliSense is happy, but builds fail. When I put the `ItemGroup/Compile` inside the 'CompileGeneratedCode' `Target`, the build succeeds but IntelliSense has errors saying it cannot find the generated code.

Comment: MSBuild has two phases: [evaluation and execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022). The 'top level' (i.e. direct children of the `Project` element) `ItemGroup` and `PropertyGroup` elements are processed in the evaluation phase. Targets and their dependency order are determined in evaluation but targets are not processed until the execution phase. IntelliSense  essentially can only see an evaluation of the project and doesn't know about dynamic changes to the set of files in the project that happen in the execution phase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255683/discussion-between-jonathan-dodds-and-brady-haden).